# Connecting Domain to nginx

Tags: nginx, networking, domain-name-system, domain, router

So I have Nginx running on ubuntu server inside proxmox VM, and it's redirecting traffic to my ghost blog, and when I use my local IP `10.0.0.143:80`, it works fine, but when I try to access using my domain name, it redirects to `/UI` and displays a 403 HTTP error.

I have in Cloudflare SSL disabled because I want to make it work without SSL first and remove one more variable that could make this not work first try and an `A record pointed to my public IP`.

I also tried disabling my firewall in my router to see if that was the problem but no luck with that. Also, ports `80` and `443` are open in the router.

Also tried using my phone without being connected to the wifi, but no luck too.

**DOMAIN NAME:** zeusdevs.com

**DNS CONFIG:**
[image]

**netstat -plant output:**
[image]

**Nginx Config:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name zeusdevs.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/zeusdevs.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.143:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed. Restarted my router and it worked. Hate ISP routers so bad.

Comment: Still can't figure out why its redirecting to /ui

Comment: Reset cache and it fixed the /ui